# Is it better to yield return lookup lists or preload a static list in c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, yield

I have a simple lookup list that I will use to populate a dropdown in Silverlight.  In this example I'm using US States.

I'm trying to figure out if its better to return a static list or use the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword.  Of the following two pieces of code, which is the preferred and why?

**Version 1:** Using yield return

```
public class States
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        yield return "Alabama"; 
        yield return "Alaska";
        yield return "Arizona";
        yield return "Arkansas";
        yield return "California";
        yield return "Others ...";
    }
}
```

**Version 2:** Return the list

```
public class States
{
    private static readonly IList<string> _names;

    static States()
    {
        _names = new List<string>() {"Alabama", 
                                     "Alaska",
                                     "Arizona",
                                     "Arkansas",
                                     "California",
                                     "Others ..." };

    }

    public static IList<string> GetNames()
    {
        return _names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is : "do I want the code that calls `GetNames` to be able to modify the list ?"

- If the answer is yes, return a `IList`, implicitly saying : "read-write"
- If the answer is no, return a `IEnumerable`, implicitly saying : "read-only"

Anyway, I think you should put the state names in a resource file, rather than hard-coding them (even though that list is unlikely to change in the short term...)

Here is what I would do :

```
public static IEnummerable<string> GetNames()
{
    foreach(string name in _names) yield return name;
}
```

This way you don't directly expose the list to the "outside world"

Comment: Watch out with that least someone try: IList list = ((IList) SomeMethodThatReturnsEnumerable())

Comment: Yes, it's technically feasible... provided that it actually *is* an IList (which would not be the case for V1 code). Anyway, the return type indicates the intention, which is to provide a read-only list, but it doesn't prevent "illegal" operations.

Comment: do you mean `yield return` in your sample?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd prefer the list for this.  The only advantage the `yield` method might offer over the List here is to avoid needing to keep all the elements in memory at once, but you're going to do that anyway.

Comment: Would the fact that the objects are only in memory during their use provide any benefit?  Or would the load time out-weigh the memory cost?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd prefer the List over the iterator, though I'd also look at embedding a resource containing such a list (perhaps XML, perhaps plain text) into your assembly and read that in your static constructor.